# Creating conditional column in SQL

Tags: t-sql, if-statement, case-when

I am trying to create a conditional column in T-SQL like an if statement but rather than printing a string I would like it to pull through data from another column in the data set.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN NameDay = 'Sunday' 
          THEN [sales] 
          ELSE [SunAdj] 
    END AS AdjustedDays
FROM 
    Table
```

Basically I want it to pull data from the `[sales]` column if the day in the `NameDay` column is 'Sunday' otherwise pull it from `[SunAdj]`. I can get it to work populating a string but not data from other columns. Is this possible? If so how? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Product   category    Sales   SunAdj    NameDay  
--------------------------------------------------
Meat                  1000     3500     Sunday  
Fish                  1000     3500     Wednesday  
Bakery                1000     3500     Friday
```

I would want another column called `AdjustedDays` showing 1000 for the first row and 3500 for the others.

Comment: Please include some sample data, and ideally your table definition.  Is `NameDay` an actual column?

Comment: Yes NameDay is a column table is like the below

Comment: Please edit your _question_, rather than posting data here as comments.

Comment: Product category Sales SunAdj NameDay
Meat 1000 3500 Sunday
Fish 1000 3500 Wednesday
Bakery 1000 3500 Friday

Comment: Your current query seems fine.  Why do you think it is wrong, or what problem are you having with it?

Comment: If you can't get it to work mention the error you get

Comment: Hi Tim. Thank you for responding so quickly. I’ve left the office now but will post the full query tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick CTE setup of the data in the question:

```
; with sourceData (Product, Category, Sales, SunAdj, NameDay)
as 
(
      select 'Meat', null, 1000, 3500, 'Sunday'
union select 'Fish', null, 1000, 3500, 'Wednesday'
union select 'Bakery', null, 1000, 3500, 'Friday'
)
...
```

and we can use it to show that your statement is already correct:

```
; with sourceData (Product, Category, Sales, SunAdj, NameDay)
as 
(
      select 'Meat', null, 1000, 3500, 'Sunday'
union select 'Fish', null, 1000, 3500, 'Wednesday'
union select 'Bakery', null, 1000, 3500, 'Friday'
)
select 
    Product, Category, Sales, SunAdj, NameDay, 
    CASE when NameDay = 'Sunday' then [sales] 
         else [SunAdj] end as AdjustedDays
from sourceData
```

Just to add a little value to my answer, you can achieve the same thing with the `IIF` function:

```
; with sourceData (Product, Category, Sales, SunAdj, NameDay)
as 
(
      select 'Meat', null, 1000, 3500, 'Sunday'
union select 'Fish', null, 1000, 3500, 'Wednesday'
union select 'Bakery', null, 1000, 3500, 'Friday'
)
select 
    Product, Category, Sales, SunAdj, NameDay, iif(NameDay='Sunday', SunAdj, Sales) AdjustedDays
from sourceData
```

Both queries give the same result:

```
Product Category    Sales       SunAdj      NameDay   AdjustedDays
------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------- ------------
Bakery  NULL        1000        3500        Friday    1000
Fish    NULL        1000        3500        Wednesday 1000
Meat    NULL        1000        3500        Sunday    3500
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is working now! I think my issue was some of my columns are in different tables and it didn't seem to work alongside a join. I've created a view and ran the case statement on that which seems to have done the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got to a solution.  When you ask your next question, try to be as complete as possible in the details.  If indeed your problem was related to a join, there is no way anyone could help you identify that from the question you posted.  Anyway - happy coding.